# sql anywhere 5.5 database connect to sql anywhere 12

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I have a database file created in sql anywhere 5.5 and I need it to connect to sql anywhere 12. I tried it but it won't accept it, saying that:

> "This database was created on an older version of sql anywhere"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of SQL Anywhere 10.0, the database server no longer reads database files created with older software; they must be rebuilt. The easiest way would be to unload your database into a new one using the dbunload tool. You can do this in one step:

```
dbunload -c uid=<user>;pwd=<password>;dbf=<DBFileName> -an <newDBFileName>
```

This will create a new database file that you can then run using the version 12 server. If you can't do this in a single step (sometimes a new server has trouble unloading an old database), you may have to do it in multiple steps:

1. Use the `dbunload` utility that ships with the **old** software to unload the database using something like `dbunload -c uid=<user>;pwd=<password>;dbf=<DBFileName> unload`. This will create a directory called "unload" and store a bunch of .dat files in it. It will also create a "reload.sql" script.
2. Shut down the old server.
3. Use the `dbinit` utility that ships with the **new** software to create a new database  with the appropriate settings (encryption, collation, page size, etc.).
4. Start the new database and run `dbisql -c uid=<user>;pwd=<password> reload.sql`

*Full disclosure: I work for Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering.*

Comment: I was trying to use dbunload (through rebuild.bat) but I could not get it (v11) to unload a v7 database.

Comment: @pascal: You may have to do this in multiple steps. I'll update my answer to describe the steps.

Comment: do you need the older version of the server installed for the unload to work?

Comment: @Justin: No. The installation of SA 12 includes all of the software to do the reload.